# how to make matrix (9*9) in short way

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I want to know how to make that Matrix(9 * 9) with shorter code than this one

```
a= np.ones((9,9),dtype=int)
a[1:8,1:8:]=0
a[2:7,2:7:]=1
a[3:6,3:6:]=0
a[4:5,4:5:]=1

[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: What specifically is wrong with this approach? Please describe what you are trying to achieve and what you have already tried. Is there a performance issue with your current approach?

Comment: @Dan As written, the assignments to 0 overwrite a bunch of elements that should have stayed 1, which is why the explicit assignments to 1 are necessary. Simply omitting them is wrong without changing the code that assigns 0s.

Comment: @NickMartin i tried 
'''
x=np.ones((1,1),dtype=int)
x=np.pad(x,pad_width=1,mode='constant',constant_value=0)
x=np.pad(x,pad_width=1,mode='constant',constant_value=1)
x=np.pad(x,pad_width=1,mode='constant',constant_value=0)
x=np.pad(x,pad_width=1,mode='constant',constant_value=1)
'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
n = 9
a = np.ones((n,n),dtype=int)
for i in range(0, n//2):
    a[i+1:n-1-i,i+1:n-1-i] = i % 2
```

Comment: Might as well parameterize that `9` and bundle it up into a function.

Comment: Might be worth noting that (like OP's approach) this is O(n³), which might be relevant for large n.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not recommending this approach, but for a laugh here's a way to do it using the concept of a [maximum norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm)

```
n = 9
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(-n//2+1, n//2+1), range(-n//2+1, n//2+1))
a = 1 - (np.max((np.abs(x), np.abs(y)), 0) % 2)
```

Only really works for odd values of `n`